# `\counterwithin` not work with custom counters

Tags: macros, counters

I want to recount `section` for each new lecture. I learn that `\counterwithin` can do this job. It compiles successfully but not works right now.

Here is the relevant code.[image]

```
\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\lecture}[4]{
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \framebox{
            \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf ECCV2020
                        \hfill August 2020} }
                \vspace{4mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill Lecture #1: #2  \hfill} }
                \vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\it Lecturer: #3 \hfill Scribes: #4} }
                \vspace{2mm}}
        }
    \end{center}
    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}
}

\counterwithin*{section}{lecnum}
```

Thanks

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this. Then it is a lot easier to test your code and help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It would have been a great help if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed what you had done so we don't have to guess why you have your problem. Perhaps you should have just said `\newcounter{lecnum}[section]`

Answer (score 2):

You need `\stepcounter` in order to reset the associated counters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=7in]{geometry}

\geometry{textheight=6cm}% just to make a smaller picture

\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\counterwithin{section}{lecnum}
\counterwithin{equation}{lecnum}
\counterwithin{figure}{lecnum}
\counterwithin{table}{lecnum}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\newcommand{\lecture}[4]{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \stepcounter{lecnum}% resets every associated counter
  \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \begin{center}
    \framebox{%
      \parbox[t]{6.28in}{%
        \vspace{2mm}
        {\bfseries ECCV2020\hfill August 2020\par}
        \vspace{2mm}
        {\Large\hspace*{\fill}Lecture #1: #2\hspace*{\fill}\par}
        \vspace{4mm}
        {\itshape Lecturer: #3\hfill Scribes: #4\par}
        \vspace{2mm}
      }%
    }
  \end{center}
  \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}
}

\begin{document}

\lecture{1}{Boxes}{egreg}{Rabbittac}

This is the first lecture.

\section{First}

First section with an equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\lecture{3}{Counters}{egreg}{Rabbittac}

This is the third lecture.

\section{First}

First section with an equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I refactored the code for the box to use LaTeX commands, rather than plain ones. The commands `\bf`, `\it` and similar have been deprecated for about 25 years.

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. That really solves my problem!